# Android bluetooth device in background not as keyboard

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

I have barcode scanner who should work with my app. It is supposed to run in the background and my app is responding to input coming from the scanner in its own way. However it should not be used as a hardware keyboard and its input not directed to the firstresponder (no text entries i.e.). Currently i'm stuck with it although i know i have done a solution like described before (couple years ago for a company).

The first part of the question is now how to prevent the bluetooth device from being attached as a hardware keyboard? Can i control this behaviour or is it maybe some mode or setting that the bluetooth device must support (if yes is there name for it to check in the specifications)?

I guess if the device is not attached as a bluetooth keyboard i could establish a connection and listen to the bluetooth socket input stream for available bytes and collect them. Currently i cannot establish a connection because

```
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
socket.connect();
```

throws an `java.io.IOException` with message `read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1`. Any ideas why i cannot connect to the socket, although the device is currently paired to my device?

EDIT: 
Because it was asked, the complete connection source code

```
private void initBluetooth() {
    BTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (BTAdapter == null) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "no BT Adapter");
        return;
    }

    if (!BTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBT, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH);
        return;
    }

    listDevices();
}
private void listDevices() {
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BTAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), String.format("Device found %s", device.getName()));
            if(device.getName().indexOf("Barcode") > 0) {
                mmDevice = device;
                try {
                    openBT();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Failed", e);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void openBT() throws IOException
{
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); 
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    //now make the socket connection in separate thread
    Thread connectionThread  = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            BTAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //connection to device failed so close the socket
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    connectionThread.start();

    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();
}
```

Comment: Does the BT scanner also have the same uuid as used above? Or does the scanner is an hid device?

Comment: Hi, no the scanner has a different UUID but i also tried with `device.getUuids()[0].getUuid()`. What do you mean by hid device? As it primarly works as a keyboard i guess it is?

Comment: OK. So in the case if scanner works like a keyboard device then you cannot make a serial connection on it using rfcomm scocket api.

Comment: Can i ask you one further question because i know i did with another device which would also work as keyboard. So basically this means i need a scanning device where i can switch of HID mode?

Comment: May be other device supports both the modes. Also you can get clarification from device manufacturer whether it support serial communication as well. Also please post your complete code that connects to the scanner device

Comment: Thank you, i will. I edited my question to show code

Comment: Try using this api createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord and also follow Bluetooth chat sample from SDK to manage the connection properly. Let me know if this works I will add it as an answer.